# Elasticsearch: Sort nested objects in all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to sort all documents with one nested object because each object 'action' is a row displayed in a list and the user want to sort the list by 'vouch'.

Here is my datas in ES :

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
  "total": 2,
  "successful": 2,
  "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
  "total": 2,
  "max_score": 1,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "qae-myobject1509618636",
        "_type": "myobject",
        "_id": "601708a8-684d-4321-910b-a6ac61f986a8",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
        "id": "601708a8-684d-4321-910b-a6ac61f986a8",
        "actions": [
        {
              "id": "cc454d55-e49f-45d3-89a9-c898e8b05289",
              "vouch": "C",
              "notice": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
        }
        ,
        {
              "id": "2f1f5964-f4e2-4df2-8895-7c6535d09255",
              "vouch": "B",
              "notice": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
        }
     ]}
  }
  ,
  {
        "_index": "qae-myobject1509618636",
        "_type": "myobject",
        "_id": "c7d59a3b-5c86-42d0-809c-139a996a3c34",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
        "id": "c7d59a3b-5c86-42d0-809c-139a996a3c34",
        "actions": [
        {
              "id": "255dfb74-2576-414d-8d2d-63981ee92e73",
              "vouch": "D",
              "notice": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
        }
        ,
        {
              "id": "c26d56b8-144a-4bed-bbdc-7fdb2eca63b1",
              "vouch": "A",
              "notice": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
        }
  ]}
  }
  ]
  }
  }
```

I need to sort all 'actions' (my nested object) by 'vouch' in alphabetical order. Sadly, ES sort 'actions' by document. So I have the result :

{B, C}, {A, D} instead of {A, B, C, D}

How can I sort my documents to get one response with all nested object sorted correctly (and not by document).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what have you tried? how did it fail?

Comment: You might have the wrong index structure for such a requirement. ES gives you back documents, it can give you sub-sets of nested documents and you can maybe use `filter_path` to "format" the output, but I don't think you can ask ES to give you back only the nested documents sorted. You need to change the structure of your indices. Or do the sorting in your client code.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for your help. I will create a new index with the nested object only to perform my sort.